# How do Jehovah Witnesses come to the conclusion that the Holy Spirit is a force?

Tags: nature-of-god, jehovahs-witnesses, pneumatology

If it has been long recognized that three primary attributes of personality are mind, emotion and will. In my mind tho following verses indicate the Holy Spirit fulfills these basic attributes:

1. Corinthians 2:10 states it searches all things.
2. 1 Corinthians 2:11 says it knows the thoughts of God
3. Romans 8:27 says God knows the mind of the spirit.

Yet somehow Johavahs Witnesses come to a rather different conclusion. Their Watch Tower publications consistently refers to him as an abstract force. How do they justify this belief, specifically in light of the above Scriptures and definition?

Comment: "If it has been long recognized that three primary attributes of personality is mind, emotion and will." - Source?

Comment: Yeah, who's definition of personality is that? Certainly not modern psychology. Must be a theologian or philosopher. The question is who and what makes you think JW's believe that?

Comment: @fredsbend A person I have been speaking to that's a JW!

Comment: Are you referring to a personality or the Holy Spirit?

Comment: What's the psychologist say?

Comment: Psychology. About.com agrees

Comment: I'm searching psychology.about.com for anything that confirms what you've said. I cannot find it. Perhaps you mean something other than personality as it is typically defined "personality is a pattern of relatively permanent traits and unique characteristics that give both consistency and individuality to a person's behavior." [source](http://psychology.about.com/od/overviewofpersonality/a/persondef.htm). I don't know exactly what JW's mean when they say the HS is a force, not a person. Does it think or only represent thoughts, etc.? That would go a long way in understanding this question.

Comment: From what I had gathered it was meaning force such as wind electricity etc. But I will clarify that for sure tomorrow. As for psychology.about.com I simply googled psychology of personality and went to that website.

Comment: From all the searches I've done they all say pretty much the same thing as far as personality goes. Can you give me a reference to anything that does not agree with that?

Comment: You did notice the "it" in your own quotes there right? That's one of the biggest arguments against the personality of the Spirit, namely that in Greek it has the grammatical neuter gender (it) rather than the masculine (he) that the KJV forces onto it to save Trinitarian orthodoxy. In Hebrew, however, spirit has the grammatical feminine gender (she), which is possibly why some Gnostic sects held the Spirit to be feminine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking the JWs to justify their beliefs against what appear to be an idiosyncratic definition of personality.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple supporting reasons Jehovah's Witnesses believe the Spirit is a force, rather than a person. Some are circumstantial in nature; others are more direct.

- **Definition** This is a natural meaning of "spirit". Is the *spirit of happiness* a thinking entity? No. It's "the activating or essential principle influencing a person" (Merriam-Webster). Likewise, the *spirit of God* is the force, or activating principle, of God.
- **Source references** The Greek New Testament only uses the neuter gender when referring to the Holy Spirit: *it*, not *he*. Furthermore, there the Spirit is never called by a "personal" name. Both are unlike the personal, masculine references to Jehovah (God the Father) and Jesus (Son of God). Why the differences? Because the Spirit is a *thing*, not a *person*.
- **Man-made Trinity** JWs believe *Trinitarianism* is the product of the human Council of Alexandria and the Council of Constantinople. This isn't a direct reason to believe the Spirit is abstract per se, but it is a reason to distrust the common interpretation of God, which for mainstream Christianity differs little from these flawed councils.
- **Nature** The Spirit is often referred to as a substance.

  > I shall have to take away some of the spirit that is upon you and place it upon them.
  >
  > *Numbers 11:17*
  >
  > After that I will pour out my spirit on every sort of flesh, And your sons and your daughters will prophesy, Your old men will dream dreams, And your young men will see visions.
  >
  > *Joel 2:28*

  When have you ever heard anyone being divided in parts amongst people or poured on them? It's more akin to a substance than a person.
- **Consistent with human "spirits"** Jehovah's Witnesses do not believe humans have a literal spirit or soul independent of a physical body. Our *spirit* is our life(force), not a ghost. If you believe that human spirits are abstract, it's easier to believe that God's spirit is likewise abstract. See ["Soul" and "Spirit"](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/books/bible-teach/soul-and-spirit-what-do-these-terms-really-mean) for reasons for this belief about human spirits.

In relation to the scriptures you mentioned, JWs will point out

- **Personification**

  > True wisdom itself keeps crying out in the very street.
  >
  > *Proverbs 1:20*
  >
  > ...your brother's blood is crying out to me from the ground
  >
  > *Genesis 4:10*

  Neither Abel's blood as it lay on the ground nor wisdom in the street actually made any sounds. Nor were they any sense a "person".

There are dozens upon dozens of such personifications in the Bible, including the three you mentioned. Using them to imbue every abstract concept like these with life would be inappropriate.